# Delete a row from mongodb database in azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am an azure newbie who has a mongodb database on Azure cloud storage. I am trying to delete a row with a specific value from the Query explorer in Azure, but I keep getting this error. Am I missing something?
[image]

delete from users where _id='...' doesnt work
neither does delete * from users where _id='' work

this works perfectly even if am doing SQL on a mongodb database while querying
[image]

Comment: If you have a MongoDB database don't you have to use mongo syntax and not SQL? https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/remove-documents/

Comment: @Erik check my update, the select query works perfectly in sql syntax

Comment: tried to write `delete` in small letters (it's not marked as a keyword in the explorer)? Just guessing at this point, don't know how Azure actually translates the queries.

Comment: i also tried that, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Microsoft DocumentDB (not mongoDB). DocumentDB is available on Azure and supports SQL-like queries.

I suggest taking a look at the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/

According to the docs INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE are only available through the REST API and not in the query language.

Comment: i am using mongodb for sure as i selected it while creating the collection , also if i was using document db i would have the option to edit add remove documents through a visual editor that MS provides only for document db

Comment: Sami is correct - you're using a DocumentDB database, but with MongoDB compatibility enabled for your collection. The Query Explorer, via the portal, only supports DocumentDB SELECT queries.